# Vertical scrollbar inside table without display:block

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to have a vertical scrollbar inside `<tbody>` of a table and have `display:table` on table and not use `display:block` anywhere inside table.

Comment: Probably. Why not? What have you tried? Please [edit] your question and post your [code] as a [mcve]. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead?

Answer (score 0):

for the scroller part, add this to the tag you want to scroll:

```
style="overflow-y: scroll;"
```

Comment: Overflow property doesn’t apply to table grouping elements. That can be fixed by setting display property of table to block. My question is if there is any other way.

Answer (score 0):

add this style as desired:

style="overflow-y:auto;

for horizantal: