# Possible to have overflow: scroll without display: block?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table:
CSS:

```
.content-table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: var(--secondaryBg);
    font-size: 0.9em;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    max-height: 55vh;   
}
```

I want to add an `overflow: scroll` to be able to scroll inside the table. The problem occurs when I apply `display: block`. Without the `display` setting all the columns take the whole width, but with `display: block` there is alot of white space on the right of the column to the left.

These are the other settings applied to the table:

```
.content-table thead{
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.content-table th,
.content-table td {
    padding: 12px 15px;
}

.content-table td{
    width: 18%;
}

.content-table tr:not(:first-child){
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.content-table tr:not(:first-child):hover{
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I found this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52521304/vertical-scrollbar-inside-table-without-displayblock but it doesnt answer my question.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood, but you want to have fixed top, and movable other content in table?

Answer (score 0):

## Possible solution

Hi, I don't know whether this suits you, but I hope it helps! Anyways, here is how to do it. Make a *simple* `table` with any amount of content you'd like to have. In this table, we'll have a **fixed top/head**, but **movable content inside of a table.** **Sorry, for the bad formatting code! :(**

### HTML

```
<table class="fixed_header">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Col 1</th>
          <th>Col 2</th>
          <th>Col 3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Text</td>
          <td>Text</td>
          <td>Text</td>
          <td>Text</td>
          <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Text</td>
          <td>Text</td>
          <td>Text</td>
          <td>Text</td>
          <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Text</td>
          <td>Text</td>
          <td>Text</td>
          <td>Text</td>
          <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Text</td>
          <td>Text</td>
          <td>Text</td>
          <td>Text</td>
          <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Text</td>
          <td>Text</td>
          <td>Text</td>
          <td>Text</td>
          <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

### CSS

```
.fixed_header {
      width: 400px;
      table-layout: fixed;
      border-collapse: collapse;
}
.fixed_header tbody {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
      height: 100px;
}
.fixed_header thead tr {
      display: block;
}
.fixed_header thead {
      background: black;
      color: #fff;
}
.fixed_header th,
.fixed_header td {
      padding: 5px;
      text-align: left;
      width: 200px;
}
```

**If you want to see in your browser, [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/qscL3faw/)**